# Call external API magento 2

Tags: magento2

What is the popular way to call external API in magento2? I see some use curl while others use ZendClient. Do you guys have the helper class that wraps ZendClient that I can take a look for an example of how to use that? I am new to magento 2 and cannot find a good documentation of ZendClient

I want to write a class that wraps ZendClient so the base_url can be shared and error will be handled properly.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `\Magento\Framework\HTTP\ClientInterface`

In some projects I have also used GuzzleHttp (`\GuzzleHttp\Client`) and also curl directly. If you have the latest version of Magento Guzzle will already be installed as it is required by Klarna.

Comment: What's difference between ClientInterface, ZendClient, Guzzle, Curl. Which one is the most used?

Comment: @coinhndp
`ClientInterface` is the Magento provided client wrapper and is currently implemented using curl,
`curl` is the library used to make the raw request which a lot of other libraries "wrap" to simplify the process,
`ZendClient` and `Guzzle` are some other wrappers.

`Guzzle` is probably the most popular and has the ability to do multiple connections simultaneously as well as promise-based requests.

Comment: Great! I will go for Guzzle. Do you have any example of Guzzle code on github?

Comment: @coinhndp Simple example here http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/ Do take a look at the promise/multiple request functionality, It could have really helped me in the past but I didn't have time but could be a real help possibly.

Answer (score 0):

**ZendClient** has a problem with API response HTTP/2
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/19441
**Guzzle** is the safe choice